# Copying single selected polygon from large ArcSDE feature class in less than 10 seconds?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, enterprise-geodatabase, performance

I have selected a single polygon, which is large but not massively complex, from an ArcSDE 9.3 for Oracle feature class with 3.5 million polygons using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 SP3.

I would simply like to copy it out via ArcPy into a new shapefile (or file geodatabase feature class) and to do so in less than 10 seconds.

So far I have not been able to get it to happen in less than about 5-6 mins.

I think I need to try and take advantage of the processing environment (arcpy.env.extent) during the CopyFeatures, but if I set that to the values returned by getSelectedExtent and do the copy the time taken still seems to be 5-6 mins.

If instead I could get at a centroid x,y (and one that is guaranteed to fall inside the polygon) then I could use that to buffer a tiny amount and use that to set arcpy.env.extent and I would expect the time to come down to around 10 seconds.

However, to get at the centroid I think I still need to use CopyFeatures to get it out into a geometry first which seems Catch 22.

The 10 second target comes from [Quickest way to select ArcSDE polygon by point in ArcGIS Desktop using ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12448/what-is-quickest-way-to-select-polygon-by-point-in-arcgis-10-using-arcpy) which is another question based on the same dataset.

Comment: Can the polygon be generalized first?

Comment: Have you tried timing how long each step in your script takes? For example, try timing the opening of a SearchCursor on a feature layer with a selection. Only the selected rows will be returned. If you have an empty template feature class you could simply insert the read row into it using an InsertCursor. This may be faster than CopyFeatures.

Comment: @Mapperz Generalization is not an option in this case because I'm dealing with cadastral parcels.

Comment: @blah238 I think opening the SearchCursor on 3.5 million features in an ArcSDE for Oracle geodatabase is likely to be very slow (at least at 10.0) but I'll try to test that today in case I am wrong.

Comment: Why not transform the polygon with an ETL?

Comment: Have you tried extracting it via a non spatial query using the ObjectID or another indexed field?

Comment: @Julien I have no ETL tools available to use at this client's site but I'm not sure that an ETL could take a layer selection as input anyway.

Comment: @CraigWilliams The polygon has been selected interactively so within the script I'm thinking the only way I can find out its ObjectID or other field values from ArcPy is by opening a SearchCursor.  Taking a step back what I am trying to do is very similar to a Workstation WRITESELECT/READSELECT to take a layer selection to the same layer from one data frame to another.

Comment: With FME, for each shapefile it finds, it checks to see if that file is requested by looking at the list of IDs specified in the mapping file. If a match is made or no IDs were specified in the mapping file, the shapefile is opened to be read. The Shape reader extracts features one at a time from the file and passes them on to the rest of the FME for further processing.

Comment: @Julien FME is not available but, in any case, the data source is an ArcSDE for Oracle geodatabase rather than a shapefile or collection of shapefiles.  Also, and I could be wrong, I would not expect FME to be able to take a Layer Selection as input.

Comment: I think you are correct PolyGeo, I am not sure what Julien is driving at. Also FME is not exactly known for its speed.

Comment: How are you searching for the polygon?  Have you tried updating your DB stats on that feature class?  Have you checked to see if an index would help?

Comment: @blah238 I just ran the test of opening a SearchCursor on the table and found that it takes 2 mins 5 secs.  That's noticeably better than the 5-6 mins of my CopyFeatures method so I'll switch to using that.

Comment: @Jamie Polygon can be searched for using any available method - it is at the desktop users discretion so the case I'm trying to cover off on is when they they select it by pointing in the screen.  The geodatabase that holds the data is not one that I can tinker with settings on because it is performing excellently for its MANY users (who do not want to do what I have been asked to do - which is to try and transfer a selection set from the same 3.5 million polygon layer in two data frames from one to the other - preferably in a second or two but 10 secs or so would probably be OK).

Comment: @PolyGeo, at least asking your DBA about stats on the feature clas should not negatively impact any users.  I do totally understand.

Comment: @Jamie Some more timings I included in an ArcGIS Idea (http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bscKAAQ) that I just posted lead me to conclude that what I am after is another route to Copy Features rather than a better configured ArcSDE.

Comment: @PolyGeo, I would suggest adding the solution noted in your question as an actual "answer" below.  It will be a lot easier for others to find, and it is perfectly OK to answer your own question if you have found a suiteable answer on your own.

Comment: @RyanDalton Thanks for that advice which I have now followed. Thought I had tried to answer my own question in the past without success but, in any event, I'm glad that is possible to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this question can be found as a comment to an [ArcGIS Idea](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bscKAAQ) I posted when I concluded from discussion here that I really had hit a performance limitation that could only be addressed through an ArcGIS/ArcPy enhancement.

Fortunately, the Copy Features I was hoping to do in 10 seconds or less can be done in 4-5 seconds by downloading a script called [Make Definition Query from a Selection](http://resources.arcgis.com/gallery/file/Geoprocessing-Model-and-Script-Tool-Gallery/details?entryID=615C1209-1422-2418-8855-F5BF7BB16A78) to run prior to the Copy Features.

I am indebted to Chris Fox for pointing me at it.

Comment: Good to hear that selection set performance is improved in arcpy in 10.1. One possible explanation as to why the linked script runs much faster than opening a SearchCursor is that the default option ("OID") looks at the `fidset` of the layer -- this is probably where the performance improvement is achieved, assuming that is the option you are using.

Comment: @blah238 You are right that OID & fidset are the key to the solution because from Bruce Harold's Python script he says as a comment "Build a list of key field values.  In the default case of using the OID field, just grab the FIDSet."  Until your comment I'd not twigged to that - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the indexes for the SDE Featureclass. Create spatial and attribute indexes that will definately help you in querying when working in the SDE Environment. For the attribute indexes build index for the column in which you want to perform search. Also analyzing your fc will definately help. Let me know if it works out for you.

Comment: I'm confident that the issue I'm trying to describe is not one of how the ArcSDE layer is configured.  As you will be able to see in an ArcGIS Idea I just posted (http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000bscKAAQ) the Copy Features can be done sub-second anytime you know an expression to isolate it but if you picked it interactively then you are back to several minutes of wait time to copy it out.